# One class and many implementations

Tags: php, class, design-patterns

In my application I have a class `Database`, which contains some methods and static methods. I don't expect these methods has changed everytime, but their implementation can be changed (eg. by changing the way of data storage from SQL database to file based solution). Thus, in my application I would always refer to the `Database` class and be able to choose the implementation of this class.

```
// Code to select implementation for class Database

$db = new Database();
$data = $db->load();
$db->store($data);

$db = Database::defaultDatabase();
$db->store($data);
```

I could create a few `Database` classes with different implementations in separate files, and depending on the needs, include file with the required implementation. But I'd rather be able to choose implementation from code. I have not idea how to do it properly and in accordance with good development practice. Maybe some design pattern? The first thing that comes to my mind is the *strategy* or *factory method*, but I do not see the use for these patterns in this case.

Comment: I'm confused that you say "the first thing that comes to mind is factory method or strategy" yet you appear confused. Why did they come to mind?

Comment: Strategy, becouse I have database and different strategies of storing and loading data. But it not works with code above. Factory method becouse I have some crazy idea, but it was to crazy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this moment I think, that the best solution is PHP function `class_alias` ([link to manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php)). It works the way I wanted. I can create classes like `TextFileDatabase`, `MySqlDatabase` etc. which implements `DatabaseInterface` (or simly have the same methods without implementing any interface, but solution with `DatabaseInterface` is safer for me, becouse I don't have to remember which methods I should implement). And at start of the script I can select default implementation via `class_alias`.

```
class_alias('TextFileDatabase', 'Database');

$db = new Database();
$data = $db->load();
$db->store($data);

$db = Database::defaultDatabase();
$db->store($data);
```